# Unityの衝突判定

Tags: unity2d

Unityを始めたばかりの初心者です。
Unityでゲームを作っているのですが、プレイヤーとエネミーが衝突した時の判定がうまくいかず悩んでいます。
具体的にはプレイヤーのコードを

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
{   
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("地面"))
    {
        Debug.Log("着地");
    }
    if (col.gameObject.CompareTag("エネミー"))
    {
        Debug.Log("衝突");
    }
}
```

としているのですが、ログを見ると地面の着地はうまくいっているのですが、エネミーとの衝突が1回のみ衝突してるはずがログに2回「衝突」と表示されてしまいます。
どうすれば1回の衝突で1回の処理になるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

使用されているcollider の問題ではないでしょうか。
こちらを参考にしてみてください。

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1474400/ontriggerenter2d-gets-called-twice-sometimes.html

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！　スタック・オーバーフローでは、可能であればリンク先の内容を簡単にまとめて回答の中に書くことを推奨しています。リンクだけだと将来的にリンク切れする可能性があるからです。今回の場合だと「collider を polygon から circle に変えてみてください」などと書けば良いと思います。お時間あればどうぞよろしくお願いいたします <(_ _)>